# Chrome screenshots taken with selenium are black with IIS. However, it is properly taken when using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, iis, selenium-chromedriver

Screen shot taken with selenium chrome driver are black in IIS after the newest IIS update. However this problem does not occur when using Visual Studio. And also firefox driver does not have this problem with IIS.

Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

Versions
IIS: 10.0.15063.0
chrome driver: 2.30
chrome : 59.0.3071.115

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Chrome Beta Version update